# How to search a dataset and merge it with another?

Tags: r

I have two large datasets. Here is the format:

First:

```
Data Date     Ticker.  Revenue

x1               y1        z1
x10              y10       z10
...             ...      ...
```

Second:

```
Data Date     Ticker.  Price

x1               y1        p1
x2               y2        p2
...              ...       ...
x10              y10       p10
...              ...       ...
```

I want to search the second dataset to find corresponding values of Price and insert it in first dataset. So the final dataset would be:

```
Data Date     Ticker.  Revenue.  Price

x1               y1        z1      p1
x10              y10       z10     p10
...             ...      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `merge`

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("Date", "Ticker"))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it should include other variables in df. I gave revenue as an example, but it should include everything else

Comment: @azmath it would include all the other columns except the 'Date' and 'Ticker' that is common to both